# How to get the total number of commits in a specific branch in hg?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

How to get the total number of commits in a specific branch in Mercurial(hg)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Windows version.  The template just generates a generic line containing the word `node` for each node found, and `find` counts lines containing that word:

```
C:\demo>hg log -b default -T node\n | find /c "node"
526
```

Answer (score 1):

Working on a Mac or a Linux machine, I would say:

> hg log -b a-specific-branch -T "{node}\n" | wc -l

On Windows I don't know …

Comment: The hg command would be the same on Windows (unsure about the newline) but I'm not sure of a good wc alternative